# Advice about magento theme

Tags: magento, themes, rebuild

I want to build website same as www.piquadro.com (with different products). The site is on Magento. Is there a way to scrap the theme?

I try it to rebuild it, but I have never worked with Magento and I need to finish it as soon as posible.

Comment: It is better for you hire a Magento developer as well as a designer.Use other site only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about Magento and all open source platforms is that there is an extensive community of developers who work on it. If you feel like you can't do it by yourself or can't afford to hire developer, you can find free or paid version of fashion theme very similar to what you are looking on www.templatesnetwork.com or other magento theme selling websites.
Here is an example:
http://www.templatesnetwork.com/magento-themes-type/58948.html

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no way to scrape the theme.

Comment: write such sentence in comment please

Comment: But, it's the answer! :)